# Why does this C code magically print "a[2] = 98"?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int n;
  int a[5];
  int *p;

  a[2] = 1024;
  p = &n;

 /* adding any of these lines makes code to print "a[2] = 98" at output */
  p[5] = 98; //OR *(p + 5) = 98;

  printf("a[2] = %d\n", a[2]); //Prints a[2] = 98
  return (0);
}
```

I don't understand why this C code magically prints "a[2] = 98". Though, this is what I want but I want to understand it.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, so anything can happen. What probably happens is that it just calculates where `p[5]` would be and that happens to be the memory location of `a[2]`.

Comment: I want to understand this "undefined behavior".

Comment: Please see [Should I try to explain undefined behaviour?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271372/should-i-try-to-explain-undefined-behaviour)

Comment: To understand what the compiler did, you need to look at (and interpret) the assembler output. Mind you... the compiler can output different assembler for the same code with different options, with different computer load, with different phase of the moon, ...

Comment: Also see [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: `p` is not pointing to an array, so any indexing except `p[0]` is undefined. It looks as though the code is expecting a particular arrangement of the variables.

Comment: writing `p[5] = ...` makes no sense. you are just playing dangerously with your address space.

Comment: This is one thing I really really dont like on SO. closing a question just bcus you don't know the answer to it is rude and defeating the purpose of SO.
user3386109 closed this question as duplicates WHEREAS this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior
has NOT answered the question.....they are NOT the same question in the first place so they can't have same answer.

If you can't answer a question why not leave it for others who can to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend a specific memory layout, don't do it on the base of guesswork concerning the compiler's work, be explicit by using `struct` for cases like this:

```
struct {
  int n;
  int a[5];
  int *p;
} vars;
```

But you should also look up the documentation of the compiler how to force a certain alignment, for instance packed structures.

The memory layout of local variables cannot be consistently deduced from declaration order, it is undefined. And that's why your code is sayd to show [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior).

Comment: Woh woh woh!!!......take it easy Wolf. I'm more confused NOW...I'm just learning C I don't know how to use struct yet. I just want to know exactly what happened in the code in my question.

Comment: @pasignature maybe you just made a typo and originally wished to assign the pointer `p` to an address of `a`, for instance `&a[0]` which has the same value as `a` (arrays are assignment compatible to pointers), so `p=a` would be well-defined. (by itself)

Comment: @Wolf but `a[5] = 98` is out of range too.

Comment: @WeatherVane absolutely, but a[5] is not accessed in above code. If the code would be corrected in only this one point, `p=a`, you of course would be right.

Comment: @Wolf, my comment was because you said OP might have made a typo, but `p[5]` for `a[5]` is still undefined.

Comment: @WeatherVane indeed it looks like ***a couple of "typos"***. Maybe I've better asked for the intention of the code. Interestingly some people code to see what happens instead of following some well-defined goal ...